# Android - create app shortcut (action button) in notification center

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Is it possible to create kinda app shortcut or action button in notification (like WiFi or Location)

**Screenshot**

[image]

I guess it possible, because many 3rd party apps has their icons in notification center, but cannot find neither discussion about this topic nor official documentation.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are interested in, [here's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/package-summary.html) link to official documentation of quick settings tile api.